# asp.net function brings incomplete data

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am consuming an Ajax in JavaScript that I perform myself, the problem is that it is repeating the data in its last three fields; validate the query in the DB and the data is different from what the Ajax brings, I show my functions:

In asp.net I have the following function:

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Reportes> GetScrapReport(string fecha, string fechaend)
    {
        try {
            var fechaparametro = new SqlParameter("@fecha", fecha);
            var fechafinparametro = new SqlParameter("@fechafin", fechaend);
            var listareport = _context.Reportes.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT DISTINCT idscrap, fecha, modelo, elemento, nombre, numeroparte, cantidad FROM F_GetScrapReport (@fecha, @fechafin)", fechaparametro, fechafinparametro);
            return listareport.ToList();
        }
        catch 
        {
            return new List<Reportes>();
        }
    }
```

The `Reportes` model contains the following structure:

```
public class Reportes
{
    [Key]
    public int Idscrap { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }
    public string elemento { get; set; }
    public string? nombre { get; set; }
    public string? numeroparte { get; set; }
    public int? cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

The AJAX JavaScript function that I put together is as follows:

```
function GetScraptime()
{
    var j = 0;
    var fecha = document.getElementById('scraptime');
    var fechafin = document.getElementById('scraptimetwo');
    console.log(fecha.value);
    console.log(fechafin.value);
    if (fecha.value == "" || fechafin.value == "") {
        console.log("Uno de los parametros esta vacio");
    }
    else
    {
           $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "Reportes/GetScrapReport",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'fecha': fecha.value, 'fechaend': fechafin.value },
        async: true,
        success: function (result)
        {
                console.log(result.length);
                $("#tabletimescrap").html('');
                while (j < result.length) 
                {
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<tr>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].idscrap + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].fecha + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].modelo + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].elemento + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].nombre + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].numeroparte + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + result[j].cantidad + "</td>");
                    $("#tabletimescrap").append("</tr>");
                    j = j + 1;
                }
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

The query that I am making is obtained from an SQL function that I perform, I attach the function in SQL and the result of executing it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_GetScrapReport (@fecha varchar(20), @fechafin varchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN 
    (   SELECT [Scrap].IDScrap
                  ,[fecha]
                  ,M.modelo
                  ,[elemento]
                  ,P.nombre
                  ,P.numeroparte
                  ,[cantidad]
              FROM [dbo].[Scrap] FULL OUTER JOIN Scraparte Sc ON dbo.[Scrap].IDScrap = Sc.IDScrap 
              JOIN Modelo M ON dbo.[Scrap].IDModelo = M.IDModelo LEFT JOIN Parte P ON Sc.IDParte = P.IDParte
              WHERE dbo.[Scrap].fecha >= convert(varchar,REPLACE(@fecha,'"','') , 23) AND dbo.[Scrap].fecha<= DATEADD(HOUR,23.9999,convert(varchar, REPLACE(@fechafin,'"',''), 23)))
```

And finally what I get in the DB performing the query is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idscrap, fecha, modelo, elemento, nombre, numeroparte, cantidad FROM F_GetScrapReport('2022-07-06','2022-07-06')
```

[image]

The problem is that in the view, I get the following results, the **nombre**(*name*), **numeroparte**(*numberpart*) and **Cantidad**(*quantity*) columns repeat their values, which does not make sense with what is written in the DB

[image]

Comment: I see that  your controller query data with `FromSqlRaw($"SELECT DISTINCT ..`, while your SQL query didn't have `DISTINCT` word, this could be lead the result sets are different.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks for the answer, I just updated my code and tried, but it's still the same

Comment: Hmmm, I see your changes, the `DISTINCT` should not place in the SQL function, but should be the query below (that call the Function) in order to match with the query command in the controller.

Comment: You mean DISTINCT must be in the controller, but not in the SQL function?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my meaning, your query that run in SSMS shoul be `SELECT DISTINCT  idscrap, fecha, modelo, elemento, nombre, numeroparte, cantidad FROM F_GetScrapReport('2022-07-06','2022-07-06')` so the query is same with controller.

Comment: Oh, got it, I made the change in the post, but the data that my view shows hasn't changed, thanks

Comment: @Robinson In the success function of the AJAX call, can you inspect the result data being passed in before you begin your while loop.  Is it the expected data?

Comment: @cholloway Thanks for your interest, I was managed to solve the bug, I forgot to add the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `Reportes` **data model**, where I am decorating the `Idscrap` field with `[Key]` indicating that it is the identifier of the *table*, but in my query there should not be an identifier, it is a `SELECT` with several `JOIN` , so, the model I decorate it with `[Keyless]` indicating that the return of my query will not contain an identifier, thus it shows me the data as it appears in the DB.

```
[Keyless]
    public class Reportes
    {
        public int  Idscrap { get; set; } 
        public DateTime  fecha { get; set; }
        public string modelo { get; set; }
        public string elemento { get; set; }
        public string? nombre { get; set; }
        public string? numeroparte { get; set; }
        public int?  cantidad { get; set; }
    }
```